# vim : <silent> nmap

Tags: vim, silent

In vim I have this nmap

```
nmap <silent> ,mu : marks ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<CR>
```

If I don´t have Upper marks and try `,mu` I get

```
E283: No marks matching "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

why  don't show the Error output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 nnoremap <silent> ,mu :execute "try\nmarks ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\ncatch /\\V\\^Vim(marks):E283:/\nendtry"<CR>
```

By the way, is there a reason for writing `:nmap` instead of `:nnoremap`? You should not do this if you don't have a reason unless you want to run in the situation where you can't predict what will be the result of adding another mapping (directly to vimrc or by installing a plugin).

**Edit** *<sub>(sehe)</sub>*

To make things more readable, I'd suggest using a snippet like this in your `$MYVIMRC`:

```
function! ShowGlobalMarks()
    try
        marks ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    catch /E283:/
    endtry
endfu

nnoremap <silent> ,mu :call ShowGlobalMarks()<CR>
```